# Django Form is not saving file to Database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

views.py

```
from .forms import palForm
def add_form(request):
    if request.method!="POST":
        return HttpResponse("Method Not Allowed")
    else:
        form = palForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        context = {"form": form}
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request,"Successfully Added")
            return render(request,"home/pal-form.html",context)
        else:
            messages.error(request,"Failed to Add")
            return render(request,"home/pal-form.html",context)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import palabout

class palForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=palabout
        fields =['fname','lname','dob','gender','profileImage']
```

models.py

```
from pol.models import CustomUser
from django.db import models

class palabout(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    profileImage = models.FileField()
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    gender = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, choices=(('m', ('Male')), ('f', ('Female'))),
        blank=True, null=True)
    dob = models.DateField(max_length=8)
```

.html

```
<form role="form" action="{% url 'pal:add_form' %}" method="post" class="form-style-9",enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
    
            <div id="profile-container">
                <image id="profileImage" src= "{{pic.url}}" style="width:100px" /></div>
                <input id="imageUpload" type="file" name="profile_photo" placeholder="Photo" required="" capture>
                <div class="container">
                    
                        <ul class="personal-details">
                            <li>
                                <ul class="column">
                                    <li>    
                                        <label for="fname"><strong>First Name </strong></label>
                                        <input type="text" id="fname" tabindex="1"  /> 
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <ul class="column">
                                    <li>
                                        <label for="lname"> <strong> Last Name </strong></label>
                                        <input type="text" id="lname" tabindex="1" />
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <ul class="column">
                                    <li>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td for="gender"><strong>Sex:</strong></td>
                                            <td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" required>Male
                                            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <ul class="column">
                                    <li>
                                        <label for="dob"> <strong> Date of birth </strong></label>
                                        <input type="date" id="dob" value="YY-DD-MM" max="2040-01-01" >
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            
                            <ul class="column">
                                <li>
                                    {% if messages %}
                                    {% for message in messages %}
                                    {% if message.tags == 'error' %}
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger" style="margin-top:10px">{{ message }}</div>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% if message.tags == 'success' %}
                                    <div class="alert alert-success" style="margin-top:10px">{{ message }}</div>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                    {% endif %}
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="submit-div">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <button style='margin-top:10px;' type='submit' >Save</button>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

I'm trying a lot saving my database, but it's failed because many times i have got `failed to Add` but not successfully in my pages on database. Can you tell me what's problem in my page?

Comment: Try passing `form.errors` inside your `messages.error`

Comment: @RohitRahman i have got `'ErrorDict' object is not callable`

Comment: Try printing it. Like `print(form.errors)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using django for rendering the form, like
or use the name='same_as_field_name' attribute for fields

```
<input type="text" name='fname' id="fname" tabindex="1"  /> 
<input type="text" name='lname' id="lname" tabindex="1" />
.....
.....
```

or

```
{{form.fname}}
{{form.lname}}
....
....
```

for getting correct error,
then change messages.error(request,"Failed to Add") to

```
messages.error(request,form.errors)
```

Comment: Thanks! it have done well. yeah! it can do check where were you identify mistake on form.py, model.py `messages.error(request,form.errors)`

Answer (score 0):

According to your views, you are rendering template after else statement.

Instead of this:

```
   else:
        messages.error(request,"Failed to Add")
        return render(request,"home/pal-form.html",context) #here you made mistake so that's why it is not saving.
```

Do this:

```
   else:
        messages.error(request,"Failed to Add")
   return render(request,"home/pal-form.html",context)
```

And in your tempalate, you have not passed form fields in inputs.
let's pass it:

```
<form role="form" action="{% url 'pal:add_form' %}" method="post" class="form-style-9",enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
    
            <div id="profile-container">
                <image id="profileImage" src= "{{pic.url}}" style="width:100px" /></div>
                <input id="imageUpload" value="{{form.profileImage}}" type="file" name="profile_photo" placeholder="Photo" required="" capture> #here added form field
                <div class="container">
                    
                        <ul class="personal-details">
                            <li>
                                <ul class="column">
                                    <li>    
                                        <label for="fname"><strong>First Name </strong></label>
                                        <input type="text" id="fname" tabindex="1" value="{{form.fname}}" /> #here added form field
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <ul class="column">
                                    <li>
                                        <label for="lname"> <strong> Last Name </strong></label>
                                        <input type="text" id="lname" tabindex="1" value="{{form.lname}}" /> #here added form field
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <ul class="column">
                                    <li>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td for="gender"><strong>Sex:</strong></td>
                                            <td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="{{form.gender}}" required>Male
                                            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="{{form.gender}}">Female</td> #here added form field
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <ul class="column">
                                    <li>
                                        <label for="dob"> <strong> Date of birth </strong></label>
                                        <input type="date" id="dob" value="{{form.gender}}" max="2040-01-01" > #here added form field
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            
                            <ul class="column">
                                <li>
                                    {% if messages %}
                                    {% for message in messages %}
                                    {% if message.tags == 'error' %}
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger" style="margin-top:10px">{{ message }}</div>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% if message.tags == 'success' %}
                                    <div class="alert alert-success" style="margin-top:10px">{{ message }}</div>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                    {% endif %}
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="submit-div">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <button style='margin-top:10px;' type='submit' >Save</button>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: updated template also try that